# Product name change is not reflected in project navigator in Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9.4

I have one project to build my SDK framework. This project has 4 targets (watch / noWatch / obfuscated / notObfuscated).
I need 4 different product names in order to map them correctly in my APP project (which uses the SDK project to build the framework).

Previously I had the product name equal for all targets but this caused confusion in my APP project when embedding the SDK framework. My APP project has also 4 corresponding targets.

When I change the product name then the new product name is properly reflected in project navigator in section "Products" but only for 1 target. The remaining 3 targets leave the old names in project navigator.

This prevents me from setting up the parent APP project properly. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is somewhat magical. Just duplicate the target and remove the original one. The new duplicated target will start to work as expected ;-)